# How to join calendar table in order to get NULLs where there is no values in the main table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Imagine I have a table for February with users and their COVID-19 quarantine isolation violations during a single day. If the user didn't violate isolation whole day there is no such row in the table for this date.

```
user date       violations
1    2020-02-01 2
1    2020-02-03 1
1    2020-02-15 2
3    2020-02-04 1
3    2020-02-24 3
```

What type of join should I use for my query in order to show every day in February for each user and violations column value (null or 0 if there is no such row):

```
user date       violations
1    2020-02-01 2
1    2020-02-02 NULL
1    2020-02-03 1
1    2020-02-04 NULL
...
1    2020-02-29 NULL
3    2020-02-01 NULL
3    2020-02-02 NULL
3    2020-02-03 NULL
3    2020-02-04 1
...
3    2020-02-29 NULL
```

I have a calendar table for February:

```
date
2020-02-01
2020-02-02
...
2020-02-29
```

I tried a full outer join, but it works as I expected only for one user.

Comment: main table right join calendar table.  (and also join main table again to get user id's)

Comment: @jarlh doesn't work. I don't get null values for users where there is no such date in the main table when I do this:

```select *
from examples
   RIGHT JOIN (select date from calendar where calendar.date BETWEEN date'2020-02-01' and date'2020-03-01') c
on examples.day = c.date```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the existing data:

```
select c.date, u.user, v.violations
from calendar c cross join
     (select distinct user from violations) u left join
     violations v
     on c.date = v.date and u.user = v.user
```

If you have a separate table for users, then use that instead of the subquery for `u`.  After all, perhaps there are users who had no violations in February.

Comment: If there is also a "users" table, then cross join then left outer join is correct. If you must pick the users from the "violations" table, Oracle (and I assume the SQL standard?) has **partition** other join, which avoids reading the "violations" table twice.

Comment: @mathguy . . . I think the "partition" join is specific to Oracle.

Comment: I think you are right, I did a Google search for "SQL Server partition outer join" and everything that came back was about Oracle - a pretty clear sign. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a separate table of users, then you need a cross join of calendar and users, and then left outer join to the violations table, as Gordon Linoff has already shown.

However, if you **don't** have a table of users, and you must just pick them from the violations table, then you should use the **partition outer join** which exists exactly for this purpose:

```
select v.user, c.date, v.violations
from   calendar c left outer join violations v
       PARTITION BY (v.user)                      -- this is what you must add
       on c.date = v.date
order  by user,date
;
```

The benefit is that you don't have to read the violations table twice.

Note that DATE and USER and keywords and shouldn't be used as column names; I followed your lead with this, but your lead is not good.